# How to join key value table on JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, mapping

I have existing table extras & address with this example data

Table extras

```
------------------------------------------
id  |   extras_key          | extras_value
------------------------------------------
1   | name                  | John
2   | address_id            | addr-2
------------------------------------------
```

Table address

```
--------------------------------------------
addr_id     |   name            | city
--------------------------------------------
addr-2      | Office            | Jakarta
--------------------------------------------
```

how to join those tables on JPA? My code is

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name="address")
public class Address implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="addr_id")
    private String addrId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name="extras")
public class Extras implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="extras_key")
    private String extrasKey;

    @Column(name="extras_value")
    private String extrasValue;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "extras_value", referencedColumnName = "addr_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Address address;
}
```

but when I test those codes it has a false result (shows all result even with null Address) and took so much execution times on production DB (which has a lot of data), this is the example result

```
Extras{id=1, extrasKey='name', extrasValue='John', address=null}
Extras{id=2, extrasKey='address_id', extrasValue='addr-2', address=Address{addrId='addr-2', name='Office', city='Jakarta'}}
```

I tried with this query and it shows the correct result (only show one row with address)

```
SELECT * FROM extras JOIN address ON extras.extras_value = address.addr_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the query in your repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ExtrasRepository extends CrudRepository<Extras, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select extras.* from extras " +
            "inner join address on extras.extras_value = address.addr_id",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Extras> functionName();
}
```

Comment: thank you! but when i added one more table let say table "student" with column "student_id" and "name" inside "student" table, and add 1 more field "student_id" inside "extras" table, I got null value on variable "extras" inside "student" entity. i used this native query in student repository @Query(value = "select * from student JOIN extras ON student.id=extras.student_id " +
        "JOIN address on address.addr_id = extras.extras_value", nativeQuery = true), and when i execute sql query I got correct result. Am I make some mistake?

Comment: Student(id=1, name=john, extras=null)

Comment: Did you specify the relationship between the Extras entity and the Student?

Comment: yes, in Student entity, It has @OneToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id",referencedColumnName = "student_id")
    Extras extras;